# Android app: dovelop upgrade

Tags: android, build, upgrade

I have to develop some upgrade of existing Android application.
This application was not created by me, and the only source code that the manufacturer has provided me is:

- **AndroidManifest.xml** file
- **src** dir
- **res** dir

Are these file and dirs sufficient to do this?
And if so, how can I create a new android project in Eclipse with the existing AndroidManifest.xml file and src and res dir??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, click 'File'->New Android Project, give it a project name and select 'Create project from existing source' button. Then pick the location of the source folder.

Note that if this app has been published on Android Market/Google Play, you will also need the app signing keystore from whoever gave you the source code. You will need the keystore to sign the app, or otherwise you can't update it on Android Market.